# R formattable on rows (or transpose afterwards)

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, formattable

I have a horizontal data frame in R and need to conditional format it based on rows. With the formattable area function I am able to color a whole row but I can't format it based on the values in other rows.

If I transpose my data frame before, I can conditional format it as I need it, however, I can't seem to be able to transpose it back while keeping the format.

The example only lists a few of the columns I have but should illustrate the problem.

I need to conditional format the "CurrentPrice" based on the Max, Upper_Quartile etc. Later I need to use the output to attach it to a report.

```
library(formattable)
Q3 = c(1.31, 0.499, 0.1500, -0.05, -0.85,-1)
Q4 = c(3.31, 0.499, 0.1500, -0.05, -0.85,-0.2)
Q2 = c(4.31, 0.499, 0.1500, -0.05, -0.85,5)
Q1 = c(5.31, 0.499, 0.1500, -0.05, -0.85,2.3)

stats = data.frame(Q3,Q4,Q2,Q1)

rownames(stats)<-c('Max','Upper_Quartile','Median','Lower_Quartile','Min', "CurrentPrice")

formattable(stats, list(
  area(row = 6) ~ formatter("span", 
                            style =  ~ style("background-color" =  "lightgreen"
                            ))))

tStats <- t(stats)
tStats <- as.data.frame.matrix(tStats) 

formattable(tStats, list(
  CurrentPrice = formatter("span", 
                           style =  ~ style("background-color" = 
                                              ifelse(Min >= CurrentPrice, "lightgreen", 
                                                     ifelse(Max <= CurrentPrice, "red", 
                                                            ifelse( Lower_Quartile >= CurrentPrice, "aquamarine", 
                                                                    ifelse( Upper_Quartile <= CurrentPrice, "darkorange", NA))))
                           ))))
```

[RowFormatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WylN.jpg)

[CorrectColumns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJl0O.jpg)